# Jquery Mobile fixed elements Firefox 25

Tags: android, firefox, jquery-mobile

After updating to Firefox 25 on Android (Galaxy S4) just days ago, i found an issue with fixed header in jqm 1.3.2, it seems to be positioning above the screen pulling footer and slidepanel up.
If i tap the screen the header comes in okay and positiones footer okay, then disappearing again when tapping once more.

Anyone else noticed any such problem in new FF25 on android ?

Here is a source where this scenario occurrs, ive removed all load and custom css and js as it doesnt affect the problem.

is it FF25 or is it me ??...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-15">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<title>TEST</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">

<script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/autocomplete/jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/touchswipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="jqm-mypage" data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="c">

  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="jqm-header">
   <h1 class="jqm-logo">heading</h1>
    <a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
  </div>


  <div data-role="content" class="jqm-content">

  <p>Content</p>


  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
   <h1>....</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="panel" class="jqm-nav-panel jqm-navmenu-panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-theme="c">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d" data-icon="false" data-global-nav="demos" class="jqm-list">
    <li data-role="list-divider">TEST</li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div><!-- /panel -->

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

Obviously a bug in FF25 mobile.

If i set div content a min height that is higher than the screen height, the fixed header shows fine and everything is positioned normally.

On pages where the content is less than the screen height, the fixed header disappears on pageload, pulling footer and panels up.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I'm running into the same problem. FF25, header and footer both rendering too high. Can you provide some clarity into your solution? Perhaps some CSS?